# no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:resources'

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

In spring whenever i write

 in my dispatcher-servlet.xml i get this error:-

> Blockquote SEVERE: Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 17 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 17; columnNumber: 65; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:resources'.
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:395)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:272)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:196)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5068)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5584)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1572)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1562)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 17; columnNumber: 65; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:resources'.
>       at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
>       ... 22 more

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd ">

<mvc:resources location="/resources/**" mapping="/resources/"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />
<context:component-scan base-package="id.jexpress" />   

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" />

<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Use the auto-completion in your IDE to see what you can insert at a specific text position with Ctrl+Space. Either the order of XML elements is wrong, or - what here seems to be the case - a missing spring jar. Which one eludes me.

Comment: i'd try to Ctrl+space and complete spring jar, nothing happened for this...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the schema from your classpath - the XSD is in [the subproject](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/bc14c5ba83e1f211628456bbccce7b2531aac58c/spring-webmvc/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.schemas) and gets bundled into the spring-webmvc jar.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

works fine for me